# how to add iframe in my website

Tags: iframe

i have a problem in adding iframe in my website [EAADHAR](http://www.mpep.in/p/aadhar-card.html), i want to add this website [eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in](http://www.mpep.in/p/aadhar-card.html) in  iframe of my site but when i add this iframe on my site it could not show anything its show blank page, if i add uidai.gov.in in iframe then its my website shows correctly this website in iframe, so at that time what can i do to add eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in to my site in iframe please solve my problem

working code

```html
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://uidai.gov.in" width="600" height="400" >
  
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Not working Code

```html
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in" width="600" height="400" >
  
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your site is http or https? So as the site you are adding into iframe, is it http or https?

Comment: Can you post the console log?

Comment: The eaadhar site is using https and hence you cannot load it, it has potential security risks and your browser is likely to deny it. You have to switch to https to make it work.

Comment: can you show your code as well as the console log?

Comment: Can you please update it in the question? It is complicated to read it in here.

Comment: this iframe code works but when i add subdomain of uidai then its not working

Comment: I posted the answer, please check it.

Comment: Not working when i add subdomain

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got your problem. All you need to do is add the protocol it follows to make sure that doesn't mess-up with a multi-level subdomain.

Try the following code:

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <iframe src="https://eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in" width="600" height="400"></iframe> 
</body> 
</html>
```

If something is not working, let me know.

**UPDATE**

> The server sets the `X-Frame-Options` header to explicitly stop you
>   embedding the site in a frame. There is nothing you can do about this
>   - if the server sets that header your browser will not display the content.

The only thing I can think of is to proxy an AJAX request for the url, then look at the headers, and if it doesn't have `X-Frame-Options`, then show it in the `iframe`.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check it. It is not your fault.

Comment: at that time any way to display that website on my site page

Answer (score 0):

The second, non-working URL is sending a header indicating it should not be iframed.

```
$ curl -I https://eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Sat, 30 Apr 2016 18:06:54 GMT
> Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> ...
```

That `X-Frame-Options` value tells your browser to only allow websites on the same domain name to iframe it. Any other site is forbidden from doing so.

Comment: any way to display that website on my site page

Comment: @SwabhavMishra No. The authors of that site have specifically forbidden it.

Comment: @SwabhavMishra You'd have to proxy the page. Complicated, prone to breakage, and good chance of getting shut down by them if they detect it.

Comment: ohkk, any way to add features of that site in my site for example any information can get without leaving my site

Comment: if people want to download aadhar card by filing there information on eaadhar.uidai.gov.in so i want to add this feature on my site, wheres people can easily fill all details on my site and get downloaded there aadhar card from my site

Comment: @SwabhavMishra What **you** want to do is irrelevant. The site owner has said no, very possibly for security reasons.